# Rewriting Dynamic SQL Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

I am trying to rewrite a Dynamic SQL Stored Procedure to avoid treating the SQL statement as a string

The original stored procedure

```
select @sql = 'select AM.AUTHNO, '
        select @sql = @sql + 'AST.DESCR, '
        select @sql = @sql + 'AM.MEMBID_DISP as ''MEMBID'', '
        select @sql = @sql + 'convert(varchar(25),isnull(AM.MEMBNAME,'''')) as member_name, '
        select @sql = @sql + 'isnull(MM.SEX,'''') as member_sex, '
        select @sql = @sql + 'isnull(MM.BIRTH,'''') as member_birth, '
        select @sql = @sql + 'convert(varchar(25),isnull(HC.HPNAME,'''')) as member_healthplan, '
        select @sql = @sql + 'convert(varchar(25),isnull(PM.lastname,'''') + isnull('', '' + PM.firstname,'''')) as provider_name, '
        select @sql = @sql + 'PM.PROVID_DISP as ''PROVID'', '
        select @sql = @sql + '''1'' as ''SORT_ORDER'', AM.MEMBID as ''MEMB_KEYID'', AM.AUTHPCP as ''PROV_KEYID'' '
        select @sql = @sql + ', AM.DBKEY as ''DBKEY'' '
        select @sql = @sql + ', (select DESCR from DB where [KEY] = AM.DBKEY) as ''IPA'' '
        select @sql = @sql + ', AM.AUTHDATE, AM.REQDATE '
        select @sql = @sql + 'from Z_AUTH_MASTERS AM, Z_AUTH_STATUS AST, Z_PROV_MASTERS PM, Z_MEMB_MASTERS MM, Z_HP_CONTRACTS HC '
        select @sql = @sql + 'where AM.DBKEY in (' + DBO.C_SP_AUTH_SEARCH_DBKEY(@DB_KEY,@GUID) + ') '  -- **** CUSTOM
        select @sql = @sql + 'and AM.DBKEY = PM.DBKEY ' 
        select @sql = @sql + 'and AM.AUTHPCP = PM.PROVID '
        select @sql = @sql + 'and AM.DBKEY = AST.DBKEY ' 
        select @sql = @sql + 'and AM.STATUS = AST.CODE '
        select @sql = @sql + 'and AM.DBKEY = MM.DBKEY ' 
        select @sql = @sql + 'and AM.MEMBID = MM.MEMBID '
        select @sql = @sql + 'and AM.DBKEY = HC.DBKEY ' 
        select @sql = @sql + 'and AM.HPCODE = HC.HPCODE '
        if @REFPROV <> '%'
            select @sql = @sql + 'and AM.AUTHPCP_DISP = ''' + @REFPROV + ''' '
        if @AUTHNO <> '%'
            select @sql = @sql + 'and AM.AUTHNO like ''' + @AUTHNO + ''' '
        if @STATUS <> '%'
            select @sql = @sql + 'and AM.STATUS = ''' + @STATUS + ''' '
        if @REQPROV_FIRST <> '%'
            select @sql = @sql + 'and PM.FIRSTNAME like ''' + @REQPROV_FIRST + ''' '
        if @REQPROV_LAST <> '%'
            select @sql = @sql + 'and PM.LASTNAME like ''' + @REQPROV_LAST + ''' '
        if @MEMB_FIRST <> '%'
            select @sql = @sql + 'and MM.FIRSTNM like ''' + @MEMB_FIRST + ''' '
        if @MEMB_LAST <> '%'
            select @sql = @sql + 'and MM.LASTNM like ''' + @MEMB_LAST + ''' '
        if @MEMB_ID <> '%'
            select @sql = @sql + 'and AM.MEMBID_DISP like ''' + @MEMB_ID + ''' '
        if @REQDATE_OP = 'E'
            select @sql = @sql + 'and AM.REQDATE = ''' + @REQDATE_BEGIN + ''' '
        if @REQDATE_OP = 'B'
            select @sql = @sql + 'and (AM.REQDATE >= ''' + @REQDATE_BEGIN + ''' and AM.REQDATE <= ''' + @REQDATE_END + ''') '
        if @AUTDATE_OP = 'E'
            select @sql = @sql + 'and AM.AUTHDATE = ''' + @AUTDATE_BEGIN + ''' '
        if @AUTDATE_OP = 'B'
            select @sql = @sql + 'and (AM.AUTHDATE >= ''' + @AUTDATE_BEGIN + ''' and AM.AUTHDATE <= ''' + @AUTDATE_END + ''') '
        if @EXPDATE_OP = 'E'
            select @sql = @sql + 'and AM.EXPRDATE = ''' + @EXPDATE_BEGIN + ''' '
        if @EXPDATE_OP = 'B'
            select @sql = @sql + 'and (AM.EXPRDATE >= ''' + @EXPDATE_BEGIN + ''' and AM.EXPRDATE <= ''' + @EXPDATE_END + ''') '
        if @FILTER <> '%'
            select @sql = @sql + 'and ' + @FILTER + ' '

        -- only show auths where the Authpcp or reqprov are providers that are linked to this user
        if @IS_SUPER=0
            begin
            select @sql = @sql + 'and ((AM.AUTHPCP in (SELECT PROVID from USER_PROVIDERS where USER_ID = ' + convert(varchar(10),@USER_ID) + ' and DBKEY in (' + DBO.C_SP_AUTH_SEARCH_DBKEY(@DB_KEY,@GUID) + '))) '
            select @sql = @sql + 'or (AM.REQPROV in (SELECT PROVID from USER_PROVIDERS where USER_ID = ' + convert(varchar(10),@USER_ID) + ' and DBKEY in (' + DBO.C_SP_AUTH_SEARCH_DBKEY(@DB_KEY,@GUID) + ')))) '
            end


        -- add sort code here
        select @sql = @sql + 'order by SORT_ORDER asc, '
        if @SORT_COLUMN = 1
            select @sql = @sql + 'AM.AUTHNO desc, '
        if @SORT_COLUMN = 2
            select @sql = @sql + 'AM.STATUS asc, '
        if @SORT_COLUMN = 3
            select @sql = @sql + 'AM.MEMBID_DISP asc, '
        if @SORT_COLUMN = 4
            select @sql = @sql + 'MM.LASTNM asc, '
        if @SORT_COLUMN = 5
            select @sql = @sql + 'MM.SEX asc, '
        if @SORT_COLUMN = 6
            select @sql = @sql + 'MM.BIRTH asc, '
        if @SORT_COLUMN = 7
            select @sql = @sql + 'HC.HPNAME asc, '
        if @SORT_COLUMN = 8
            select @sql = @sql + 'PM.LASTNAME asc, '
        if @SORT_COLUMN = 9
            select @sql = @sql + '''IPA'' asc, '

        -- trim off last ', '
        select @sql = left(@SQL,len(@SQL)-1)
        exec sp_executesql @sql
```

This is what I have so far

```
        SELECT
            AM.AUTHNO as Auth_No,
            AST.DESCR as Descr,
            AM.MEMBID_DISP as Memb_Id,
            CONVERT(varchar(25), ISNULL(AM.MEMBNAME,'')) as Member_Name,
            ISNULL(MM.SEX,'') as Member_Sex,
            ISNULL(MM.BIRTH,'') as Member_Dob,
            CONVERT(varchar(25), ISNULL(HC.HPNAME,'')) as Member_Hp,
            CONVERT(varchar(25), ISNULL(PM.LASTNAME,'') + ISNULL(', ' + PM.FIRSTNAME, '')) as Provider_Name,
            PM.PROVID_DISP as Prov_Id,
            '1' as SORT_ORDER,
            AM.DBKEY as Db_Key,
            (SELECT DESCR FROM DB WHERE [KEY] = AM.DBKEY) as Ipa,
            AM.AUTHDATE,
            AM.REQDATE              
        FROM
            Z_AUTH_MASTERS AM,
            Z_AUTH_STATUS AST,
            Z_PROV_MASTERS PM, 
            Z_MEMB_MASTERS MM, 
            Z_HP_CONTRACTS HC
        WHERE
            AM.DBKEY IN ( DBO.C_SP_AUTH_SEARCH_DBKEY(@DB_KEY, @GUID))
            AND AM.DBKEY = PM.DBKEY
            AND AM.AUTHPCP = PM.PROVID
            AND AM.DBKEY = AST.DBKEY
            AND AM.STATUS = AST.CODE
            AND AM.DBKEY = MM.DBKEY
            AND AM.MEMBID = MM.MEMBID
            AND AM.DBKEY = HC.DBKEY
            AND AM.HPCODE = HC.HPCODE
            AND (@STATUS IS NULL OR (AM.STATUS = @STATUS))
            AND (@REFPROV IS NULL OR (AM.AUTHPCP_DISP = @REFPROV))
            AND (@AUTHNO IS NULL OR (AM.AUTHNO like @AUTHNO))
            AND (@REQPROV_FIRST IS NULL OR (PM.FIRSTNAME like @REQPROV_FIRST))
            AND (@REQPROV_LAST IS NULL OR (PM.LASTNAME like @REQPROV_LAST))
            AND (@MEMB_FIRST IS NULL OR (MM.FIRSTNM like @MEMB_FIRST))
            AND (@MEMB_LAST IS NULL OR (MM.LASTNM like @MEMB_LAST))
            AND (@MEMB_ID IS NULL OR (AM.MEMBID_DISP like @MEMB_ID))
```

I am having a difficult time coverting the following snippet of code

```
        if @REQDATE_OP = 'E'
            select @sql = @sql + 'and AM.REQDATE = ''' + @REQDATE_BEGIN + ''' '
        if @REQDATE_OP = 'B'
            select @sql = @sql + 'and (AM.REQDATE >= ''' + @REQDATE_BEGIN + ''' and AM.REQDATE <= ''' + @REQDATE_END + ''') '
        if @AUTDATE_OP = 'E'
            select @sql = @sql + 'and AM.AUTHDATE = ''' + @AUTDATE_BEGIN + ''' '
        if @AUTDATE_OP = 'B'
            select @sql = @sql + 'and (AM.AUTHDATE >= ''' + @AUTDATE_BEGIN + ''' and AM.AUTHDATE <= ''' + @AUTDATE_END + ''') '
        if @EXPDATE_OP = 'E'
            select @sql = @sql + 'and AM.EXPRDATE = ''' + @EXPDATE_BEGIN + ''' '
        if @EXPDATE_OP = 'B'
            select @sql = @sql + 'and (AM.EXPRDATE >= ''' + @EXPDATE_BEGIN + ''' and AM.EXPRDATE <= ''' + @EXPDATE_END + ''') '
        if @FILTER <> '%'
            select @sql = @sql + 'and ' + @FILTER + ' '
```

I've tried implementing a CASE statement, but the syntax is incorrect

```
 WHERE
    CASE
        WHEN @REQDATE_OP = 'E' THEN AM.REQDATE = @REQDATE_BEGIN
        WHEN @REQDATE_OP = 'B' THEN (AM.REQDATE >= @REQDATE_BEGIN AND AM.REQDATE <= @REQDATE_END)
        ....
        ....

    AM.DBKEY IN ( DBO.C_SP_AUTH_SEARCH_DBKEY(@DB_KEY, @GUID))
    AND AM.DBKEY = PM.DBKEY
    AND AM.AUTHPCP = PM.PROVID
```

> Is a CASE statement the correct approach? If so, how should the CASE
>   statement be re-written? Are there other alternative approaches?

Comment: Two things I would suggest. First is to use ANSI-92 style joins, they have been around for more than 25 years now. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins Second is that you may have some serious performance challenges with your new approach. See this article about catch-all queries and some techniques to make them performant and safe. http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/

Comment: For all of the LIKE conditions, you can retain the default value of '%' and just use (as an example) `AND PM.FIRSTNAME like @REQPROV_FIRST`. A single percent sign in a LIKE statement matches everything. Also, the @Filter process will defeat your chance of changing this from dynamic SQL, since it appears to be an additional snippet of code added to the otherwise defined query sent in from the calling application. Unless you can code for all of the conditions that can be sent in, you will have to use dynamic SQL in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can improve the construction of this code, but with the @FILTER condition, it is unlikely that you can rid yourself of dynamic code without redefining the entire process. Here is the entire block in a single SELECT:

```
select @sql = 'select AM.AUTHNO, 
    AST.DESCR, 
    AM.MEMBID_DISP as ''MEMBID'', 
    convert(varchar(25),isnull(AM.MEMBNAME,'''')) as member_name, 
    isnull(MM.SEX,'''') as member_sex, 
    isnull(MM.BIRTH,'''') as member_birth, 
    convert(varchar(25),isnull(HC.HPNAME,'''')) as member_healthplan, 
    convert(varchar(25),isnull(PM.lastname,'''') + isnull('', '' + PM.firstname,'''')) as provider_name, 
    PM.PROVID_DISP as ''PROVID'', 
    ''1'' as ''SORT_ORDER'', AM.MEMBID as ''MEMB_KEYID'', AM.AUTHPCP as ''PROV_KEYID'' 
    , AM.DBKEY as ''DBKEY'' 
    , (select DESCR from DB where [KEY] = AM.DBKEY) as ''IPA'' 
    , AM.AUTHDATE, AM.REQDATE 
    from Z_AUTH_MASTERS AM
    INNER JOIN Z_AUTH_STATUS AST
        ON AM.DBKEY = AST.DBKEY  
        and AM.STATUS = AST.CODE 
    INNER JOIN Z_PROV_MASTERS PM
        ON AM.DBKEY = PM.DBKEY  
        and AM.AUTHPCP = PM.PROVID 
    INNER JOIN Z_MEMB_MASTERS MM
        ON AM.DBKEY = MM.DBKEY  
        and AM.MEMBID = MM.MEMBID 
    INNER JOIN Z_HP_CONTRACTS HC 
        ON AM.DBKEY = HC.DBKEY  
        and AM.HPCODE = HC.HPCODE   
    where AM.DBKEY in (' + DBO.C_SP_AUTH_SEARCH_DBKEY(@DB_KEY,@GUID) + ') ' +   -- **** CUSTOM
    CASE
        WHEN @REFPROV <> '%'
            THEN 'and AM.AUTHPCP_DISP = ''' + @REFPROV + ''' ' 
        ELSE ''
    END + CASE
        WHEN @AUTHNO <> '%'
            THEN 'and AM.AUTHNO like ''' + @AUTHNO + ''' '
        ELSE ''
    END + CASE
        WHEN @STATUS <> '%'
            THEN 'and AM.STATUS = ''' + @STATUS + ''' '
        ELSE ''
    END + CASE
        WHEN @REQPROV_FIRST <> '%'
            THEN 'and PM.FIRSTNAME like ''' + @REQPROV_FIRST + ''' '
        ELSE ''
    END + CASE
        WHEN @REQPROV_LAST <> '%'
            THEN 'and PM.LASTNAME like ''' + @REQPROV_LAST + ''' '
        ELSE ''
    END + CASE
        WHEN @MEMB_FIRST <> '%'
            THEN 'and MM.FIRSTNM like ''' + @MEMB_FIRST + ''' '
        ELSE ''
    END + CASE
        WHEN @MEMB_LAST <> '%'
            THEN 'and MM.LASTNM like ''' + @MEMB_LAST + ''' '
        ELSE ''
    END + CASE
        WHEN @MEMB_ID <> '%'
            THEN 'and AM.MEMBID_DISP like ''' + @MEMB_ID + ''' '
        ELSE ''
    END + CASE @REQDATE_OP
        WHEN 'E'
            THEN 'and AM.REQDATE = ''' + @REQDATE_BEGIN + ''' '
        WHEN 'B'
            THEN 'and (AM.REQDATE >= ''' + @REQDATE_BEGIN + ''' and AM.REQDATE <= ''' + @REQDATE_END + ''') '
    END + CASE @AUTDATE_OP 
        WHEN 'E'
            THEN 'and AM.AUTHDATE = ''' + @AUTDATE_BEGIN + ''' '
        WHEN 'B'
            THEN 'and (AM.AUTHDATE >= ''' + @AUTDATE_BEGIN + ''' and AM.AUTHDATE <= ''' + @AUTDATE_END + ''') '
    END + CASE @EXPDATE_OP 
        WHEN 'E'
            THEN 'and AM.EXPRDATE = ''' + @EXPDATE_BEGIN + ''' '
        WHEN 'B'
            THEN 'and (AM.EXPRDATE >= ''' + @EXPDATE_BEGIN + ''' and AM.EXPRDATE <= ''' + @EXPDATE_END + ''') '
    END + CASE
        WHEN @FILTER <> '%'
            THEN 'and ' + @FILTER + ' '
        ELSE ''
    END + CASE        -- only show auths where the Authpcp or reqprov are providers that are linked to this user
        WHEN @IS_SUPER=0
            THEN 'and ((AM.AUTHPCP in (SELECT PROVID from USER_PROVIDERS where USER_ID = ' + convert(varchar(10),@USER_ID) + ' and DBKEY in (' + DBO.C_SP_AUTH_SEARCH_DBKEY(@DB_KEY,@GUID) + '))) 
        or (AM.REQPROV in (SELECT PROVID from USER_PROVIDERS where USER_ID = ' + convert(varchar(10),@USER_ID) + ' and DBKEY in (' + DBO.C_SP_AUTH_SEARCH_DBKEY(@DB_KEY,@GUID) + ')))) '
    END + 'order by SORT_ORDER asc' +
    CASE @SORT_COLUMN 
        WHEN 1
            THEN ', AM.AUTHNO desc'
        WHEN 2
            THEN ', AM.STATUS asc'
        WHEN 3
            THEN ', AM.MEMBID_DISP asc'
        WHEN 4
            THEN ', MM.LASTNM asc'
        WHEN 5
            THEN ', MM.SEX asc'
        WHEN 6
            THEN ', MM.BIRTH asc'
        WHEN 7
            THEN ', HC.HPNAME asc'
        WHEN 8
            THEN ', PM.LASTNAME asc'
        WHEN 9
            THEN ', ''IPA'' asc'
    END

exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Also, one note: Why is there a sort on a constant? (the WHEN 9 condition). Just remove that, as it will not change the order of the sort at all.